# Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos Most Efficient way to Export Large Data

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to export thousands of files from a Cosmos DB, and I am wondering if there may be a more efficient way to get all these documents (but I haven't been able to figure one out by browsing the documentation and searching).

Right now I am using the FeedIterator to get my results:

```
        Database database = m_cosmosClient.GetDatabase(m_databaseId);
        DatabaseResponse databaseResponse = await database.ReadAsync();

        // The response from Azure Cosmos
        DatabaseProperties properties = databaseResponse;

        Container container = databaseResponse.Database.GetContainer(m_cosmosDbContainer);
        QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(queryString);
        QueryRequestOptions queryOptions = new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = 10000, MaxBufferedItemCount = 10000 };

        List<Article> results = new List<Article>();
        FeedIterator<Article> resultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Article>(query, null, queryOptions);
        while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<Article> response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();

            results.AddRange(response);
            if (response.Diagnostics != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nQueryWithSqlParameters Diagnostics: {response.Diagnostics.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

I am worried that without some form of multi-tasking that I could run out of memory, and then again it is always nice to have a faster run time.

Comment: Have you thought of using a ELT tool like Azure Data Factory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool is a good (and simple) option if you want to run the extract from a workstation.  It can be run interactively or automated using scripts.

Creating a job in Azure Data Factory is a bit more complex but also offers a lot more flexibility.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-migrationchoices) discusses the various options for data migration in and out of Cosmos DB.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the recommendation, and I did look into this but it is not a good fit for the situation. I am building a tool that runs the extraction in a build agent which could work potentially if the pipeline were to change, but is just not the right fit because of the other operations that need to be performed in step. However this tool does what I am looking for where it allows parallel processes to run on a single query.

Comment: While this is not a good fit for my purposes, I am going to mark this as the answer since it seems that outside of writing a custom solution there are no other options popping up.

Comment: We want to alter the documents and migrate them from one container to another. This is not possible with the Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool. If someone knows a better way to archieve this then the original question, much appriciated.